# Category list is not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have two custom post types. When I select particular category the posts which are listing is not coming accurately.    https://datingwithconfidencecoaching.com/category/confidence-love/ 
On this link there is only one post in this category still it is show more than one.

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you tried? You've told us that multiple categories aren't showing, but most of us don't read thoughts, so you'll need to help us out...

Comment: what code do you use to fetch the category post? using the category id?

Comment: https://datingwithconfidencecoaching.com/category/confidence-love/ as you can see on the link there are multiple posts which are displayed in category of confidence-love but there is actually only one post in this category.

Comment: You're going to have to show your PHP for that page.